# How can I retrieve the character position of a specific character in a file using VI?

Tags: vi, character-properties, charactercount

I need to retrieve the character position of a character in a file. How can I do this, using Vi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for the character that you want with:

`/<char_you_want>`

Then press `Ctrl-g`. You should see something like `45,28` in the bottom left. The second number is the position of the character. The first number is the line number.

Comment: Character count will be given with `g Ctrl-g`  For details, `:help g_CTRL-g`

Comment: search count: (after having used: `/<char(s)_you_want`) `:%s///gn` :)